# How many ways to arrange colors (constraints)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Ed has five identical green marbles and a large supply of identical red marbles. He arranges the green marbles and some of the red marbles in a row and finds that the number of marbles whose right hand neighbor is the same color as themselves equals the number of marbles whose right hand neighbor is the other color. An example of such an arrangement is GGRRRGGRG. let $m$ be the maximum number of red marbles for which Ed can make such an arrangement, and let $N$ be the number of ways in which Ed can arrange the $m+5$ marbles to satisfy the requirement. Find the remainder when $N$ is divided by 1000.

The reason I cant do it is because of the horrible, horrible, horrible (cant express) wording. What in the world is the meaning of:

> "finds that the number of marbles whose right hand neighbor is the same color as themselves equals the number of marbles whose right hand neighbor is the other color."

Answer (score 1):

Arrange the green marbles in a row, and let $x_1, \cdots, x_6$ be the number of red marbles in the 6 gaps created.

Since we want to maximize the number of red marbles, we can assume that $x_i>0$ for each $i$.

(If $x_1=0$, say, we can insert 2 red marbles in the first gap while maintaining the balance between right neighbors which are the same and those which are different; and

if $x_2=0$, say, we can insert 4 red marbles in the second gap while maintaining this balance.)

Then there are 10 changes in right neighbors and $(x_1-1)+\cdots+(x_6-1)$ right neighbors

which are the same, so $y_i=x_i-1\implies y_1+\cdots+y_6=10$ with $y_i\ge0$ for each $i$.

Since this equation has $\dbinom{15}{5}$ solutions, there are 3003  arrangements of the 21 marbles.

Answer (score 0):

The former means pairs like
$$\underline{GG}\overline{R\underline{R}}\underline{R}\overline{GG}RG$$
the latter means 
$$G\underline{GR}R\overline{RG}\underline{G\overline{R}}\overline{G}$$
In both cases the number is 4.

We know that $m$ is a maximum number of red marbles that we can use, so let's find the maximal configuration. Each green marble can give $2$ pairs with different colour: $RGR$, so the number is $10$. When we arrange these pairs, we will have $RGRRGRRGRRGRRGR$, which has $4$ pairs with the same colour. So, we can add few $R$'s to the left or right to have ten pairs with the same colour: $RGRRGRRGRRGRRGRRRRRRR$ ($m=16$).

If we try to regroup our sequence, making pairs like $GG$, we will get +2 pairs with similar colour, but -2 pairs with different colour (check $RGRRGR$ and $RRGGRR$). If we move some of the $R$'s inside, it will change nothing (check $GRRGRR$ and $GRRRGR$ and so on). So, I believe the task is placing six $R$'s between five blocks $RGR$, which is the number of combinations with repetition: $C_{5+6-1}^6 = 10!/(6!4!)=210$.